# Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth showing Access Denied

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm using `Youtube V3 .net library` in my web application. It is working fine on my local machine. But While I deploy it on my local IIS and try it on browser then it is showing me below exception:

```
Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=201573269273-eoteo6aj8hqq3343qi0qvc6378qt3q22.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A54419%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload" for authorization. See inner exception for details.
```

And In it inner exception it is showing me `Access Denied`.
Please help out in this.
I'm using following code:

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(JsonClient, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );
    BLL.Error.Insert("UserCredential", "No Error", "No Error");
}
```

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Why no one from google replying to this question, although they said to post question here?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?